# Android 9+ doesn't provide the incoming phone number

Tags: android, cordova

In Android 8.0 I receive the incoming phone number. 
I ask for READ_PHONE_STATE permission and the user has to grant this for the app.

However the same thing doesn't work on Android 9.0 (tested with multiple devices).

The same code for both versions.

What should I do in order to have this?
This is the code

```
package io.gvox.phonecalltrap;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.Manifest;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONArray;


public class PhoneCallTrap extends CordovaPlugin {

    CallStateListener listener;

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        prepareListener();
        listener.setCallbackContext(callbackContext);

        return true;

    }

    private void prepareListener() {
        if (listener == null) {
            listener = new CallStateListener();
            TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            TelephonyMgr.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
}

class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;

    public void setCallbackContext(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        if (callbackContext == null) return;

        String msg = "";

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            msg = "IDLE|" + incomingNumber;
            break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            msg = "OFFHOOK|" + incomingNumber;
            break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            msg = "RINGING|" + incomingNumber;
            break;
        }

        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, msg);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);

        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
    }
}
```

Note: I actually do receiving the state of the call **(IDLE, OFFHOOK, RINGING...)**, but not the phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Android 9.0 Behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#restrict-access-phone-numbers):

> Apps running on Android 9 cannot read phone numbers or phone state without first acquiring the [`READ_CALL_LOG`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CALL_LOG) permission, in addition to the other permissions that your app's use cases require.
>
> Phone numbers associated with incoming and outgoing calls are visible in the [phone state broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#action_phone_state_changed), such as for incoming and outgoing calls and are accessible from the [`PhoneStateListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener) class. Without the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission, however, the phone number field that's provided in `PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` broadcasts and through `PhoneStateListener` is empty.

It goes on to state what changes are required:

> To read phone numbers from phone state, update your app to request the necessary permissions based on your use case:
>
> - To read numbers from the `PHONE_STATE` [intent action](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element), you need both the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission and the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.
> - To read numbers from [`onCallStateChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#oncallstatechanged), you need the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission only. You don't need the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Comment: Added the READ_CALL_LOG in the manifest + prompt the user to grant this permission specifically, make the trick - I get the incoming and outgoing numbers even on Android 9.